# Microsoft SpeechSDK STT no Arabic Speech Recognition in Android

Tags: android, azure

i've tried the samples provided in Microsoft speachsdk ,it detects English Speech but no arabic recognition , I tried This method from Microsoft in order to get the language ad it returns en-US

```
public String getSpeechRecognitionLanguage()
```

My Question does it support Arabic Speech Recognition or Not ,if it Yes how to do implement the Using SpeachSDK  or any piece of code for setting the recognition language ?
Thanks For your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research the answer is Yes you can ,but Azure just don't put that on their Documentation !! , how to do it just do the following

```
private static final String SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "ar-EG";
```

then Set the language to speech Configuration

```
// create config
        final SpeechConfig speechConfig;

   speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(SpeechSubscriptionKey,             SpeechRegion);
    //Set the  speechrecgnitionlanguage     


speechConfig.setSpeechRecognitionLanguage(SpeechRecognitionLanguage);
```

Answer (score 1):

To your first question, yes [`Azure Cognitive Speech service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support) supports Arabic (ar-EG)

```
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.AudioConfig;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
```

Have a look at this [`sample code`](https://github.com/abastol1/Word-Descriptor/blob/182d7ff2f2dea5748695db2509e1132b1e3219b7/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/ocrreader/TranslateAudio.java)

Comment: Hi @Sa.   , but their is no method or something to set the recognition language it only recognize the English by default and not arabic ,is their something I can set for SpeechRecognizer. in order to recognize the arabic ??,and for your sample code he just making translation using Watson IBM api to translate the recognized speech to arabic  , this is not what I want , only Azure cognitive Speech service 
See my comment to my Question ,please

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Speech-Devices-SDK/blob/master/Samples/Android/Speech%20Devices%20SDK%20Starter%20App/Sample_Code_Walkthrough.md